# Select the Id of the latest entry with a value of ***

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to get the Id of an entry containing a value.

This is what I have used:

```
SET @ValuationId = (SELECT ValuationId FROM dbo.Valuation WHERE ValuationPropertyId = @ValuationPropertyId)
```

The problem with the above is that it selects multiple values, what can I use to get it to select the latest value?

Here is the error message I was given:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   GetLatestValuationOfPropIdThenCallUpdateComparibleSalesInfo, Line 15
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `MAX()`

```
SET @ValuationId = (SELECT MAX(ValuationId) 
                    FROM   dbo.Valuation
                    WHERE  ValuationPropertyId = @ValuationPropertyId)
```

or

```
SET @ValuationId = (SELECT TOP 1 ValuationId
                    FROM   dbo.Valuation
                    WHERE  ValuationPropertyId = @ValuationPropertyId
                    ORDER  BY ValuationId DESC)
```